# iOS: create and assign names to UIControl dynamically

Tags: ipad, ios5, dynamically-generated, uicontrol

I am trying to write data drive App where I parse json string to create UI. I have implemented this and created required controls. I am differentiating each control based on the tag assigned to them which is not efficient way. Is there anyway to assign name(other than label and textfield in following example) to UIControl while creating it dynamically?

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: myArrayCount];
for ( loop = 0;  loop< myArrayCount; loop++ ) {
    NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Label %d", loop];
    [myArray addObject:propertyName];

    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(xLabel, yLabel, widthLabel, heightLabel);
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: labelFrame];
    label.tag = loop;
    [label setText:propertyName];
    [label sizeToFit];
    [self.view addSubview:label];

    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xTextField, yTextField, widthTextField, heightTextField)];
    textField.tag = loop;
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    textField.placeholder = @"Enter parameter value";
    textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    textField.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:textField];

    yLabel = yLabel+yOffset; 
    yTextField = yTextField+yOffset;

}
```

Comment: Tag is the efficient way to identify dynamic UIControls, if you go by names then it will make things more complex.

Comment: I think so but just wondering if someone has any other solution. Every time I want to access value for particular textfield, I have to parse all textfields and get the one with the right tag and get it's value!! Moreover I have many other controls like buttons, segmented controls, uipicker etc....can I use tag for all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to use `[self.view viewWithTag:tag]` to retrieve your controls, one way to reference a dynamically created control by name would be to put it in an `NSMutableDictionary` with a dynamically generated key.

So maybe something like (a modification of your code with some of the details elided):

```
NSMutableDictionary *controlsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for ( loop = 0;  loop< myArrayCount; loop++ ) {

CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(xLabel, yLabel, widthLabel, heightLabel);
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: labelFrame];
[controlsDictionary setObject:label forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"label%d", loop]];

UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xTextField, yTextField, widthTextField, heightTextField)];
[controlsDictionary setObject:label forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"textField%d", loop]];

yLabel = yLabel+yOffset; 
yTextField = yTextField+yOffset;

}
```

Then you can retrieve the controls via statements like `[controlsDictionary objectForKey:@"label1"]`

Comment: That's actually what I am doing. The key is actually a tag value!

Comment: Cool. See also, the `viewWithTag` method on `UIView`, which should allow you to directly find a tagged subview without maintaining your own dictionary.

Comment: Wow! viewWithTag looks great I think! Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

While you can't add an iVar to `UIControl` via a category, you can add **Associated Objects**, which can be used to perform much the same function.

So, create a category on `UIControl` like this:

```
static char kControlNameKey;

- (void) setControlName: (NSString *) name
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &kControlNameKey, name, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY);
}

- (NSString *) controlName
{
    return (NSString *)objc_getAssociatedObject(array, &kControlNameKey);
}
```

There's more to it than that, I guess you'll need to check if an association exists before setting a new one, otherwise it will leak, but this should give you a start.

See the [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html) for more details

Comment: Just a quick question. Does that mean the value entered in textfield will be hold by associated object?

Comment: No, the associated object is like an iVar that you can add to an instance - in this case it's like adding an NSString property controlName to all UIControls.